# How to know which usergroup/specific access level user belongs to

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, user, user-groups

For determining whether user is a `super user`, we do something like this :

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$isAdmin = $user->get('isRoot');
if ($isAdmin) {
echo 'You are an Administrator';
```

What would be the best way to know that the logged in user belongs to a specific usergroup or has some specific viewing access level?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get an array of groups the currently logged in user belong to, you can use the following:

```
$user   = JFactory::getUser();
$groups = JAccess::getGroupsByUser($user->id);

var_dump($groups);
```

To get the names of these groups, you can run a database query (add after the code above)

```
$user   = JFactory::getUser();
$groups = JAccess::getGroupsByUser($user->id);
$groups_list = '(' . implode(',', $groups) . ')';

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select($db->qn('title'))
    ->from('#__usergroups')
    ->where($db->qn('id') . ' IN ' . $groups_list);
$db->setQuery($query);
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();

var_dump($rows);
```

To get the user's access levels, you can use the following:

```
$user   = JFactory::getUser();
$levels = JAccess::getAuthorisedViewLevels($user->id);

var_dump($levels);
```